# What is the grammatical term for using a noun without attaching a personal identifier to that noun?

Tags: grammar, nouns

I don't know how to articulate my question accurately. Here is the sentence that makes me wonder:

- *His sense of her inferiority—of its being a degradation—of the family obstacles which judgement had always opposed to inclination*
  (Jane Austen, *Pride and Prejudice*).

Austen is not explicitly saying "his judgement" so it could refer to judgement in the larger sense because of the absence of "his". I want to know the term for the thing that Austen leaves out.

Comment: [This question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/231526/whats-the-difference-between-freedom-and-the-freedom-here) is relevant.

Comment: Incidentally, that's not a sentence. It's a noun phrase, mostly devoted to listing his feelings.

Comment: There is nothing left out: family obstacles come from judgement (being judgmental) not from an individual's inclination. This doesn't have a name in grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the relative clause into a separate sentence and removing the somewhat obscure sense of "oppose," we get:

> Judgment had always set the family obstacles in opposition to inclination.

I don't know the context, but I'm not sure if Austen is actually referring solely to *his* judgment. It sounds like she means that the family obstacles had opposed inclination *in general,* not just for him but for everyone (in the family) who has ever faced them. That would explain both the use of "always" and the absence of "his."

Answer (score -1):

Here, judgement is an **abstract noun**

From Google:

> **abstract noun** (noun)
>
> a noun denoting an idea, quality, or state rather than a concrete object, e.g. truth, danger, happiness.
>
> "the website contains considerably more abstract nouns than hard facts"

Comment: Isn't it still an abstract noun if you use a pronoun ("his judgement")?

Comment: I suppose it becomes an abstract noun-phrase.